# Error Validating Signed MTOM Message CXF 3.0.6 and up

Tags: cxf, ws-security

I created a simple web service using CXF that has MTOM enabled, it also expects a time stamp and the body to be signed, it configured like this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={MyService.class})
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" })
public class CXFConfig {
    @Autowired
    Bus cxfBus;
    @Autowired
    MyService ws;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, ws);
        endpoint.publish("/MyService");
        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding)endpoint.getBinding();
        binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);
        Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE+" "+WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP);
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "wsserver.properties");
        WSS4JInInterceptor inc = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
        endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(inc);
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

My Service Interface is:

```
@WebService
@Component
public interface MyService {

    @WebMethod(action="doStuff")
    public String doStuff(@WebParam(name="FileData") MTOMMessage message) throws IOException;
}
```

My Data Type is:

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MTOMMessage {

     @XmlElement(name = "data", required = true)
     @XmlMimeType("text/xml")
     protected DataHandler data;

     @XmlElement(name = "FileName", required = true)
     protected String fileName;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I then have a client to call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String xmlLoc = "classpath:com/avum/dasn/ws/test/client-context.xml";
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(xmlLoc);
    MyService svc = ctx.getBean(MyService.class);
    MTOMMessage msg = new MTOMMessage();
    msg.setXmlData(new DataHandler(getURLForTestFile()));
    msg.setFileName("TestFileName");
    System.out.println(svc.doStuff(msg));
}
```

The client-context.xml looks like this:

```
<jaxws:properties>
  <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true"/>
</jaxws:properties>     
<jaxws:outInterceptors>
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
               <entry key="action" value="Signature Timestamp"/>
               <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="wsclient.properties"/>
               <entry key="user" value="ws-security" />
               <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.co.test.PasswordCallbackHandler"/>
            </map>
         </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
</jaxws:outInterceptors>
```

If I’m using CXF version 3.0.5 or lower this works fine.  However if I use 3.0.6 or later I get “A security error was encountered when verifying the message.”.  On the server I’m getting messages like “Couldn't validate the References”. This is because the server doesn’t get the same DigestValue that comes across in the ds:DigestValue element.

I think it has something to do with the way MTOM message are handled by the server side code because if I disable MTOM (on the client and server) then it works fine. I’m not sure how to get this working in later versions of CXF.  Does anyone have any ideas what I’m doing wrong?

Thanks 
David

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Did you manage to solve this problem or did you open  an issue  ?

Comment: A opend Jira issue with same question https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7172

Comment: I never did get it working, I ended up disabling MTOM and going that route.  Thanks for opening the issue.  The response to it says that Signature + MTOM does not work in CXF at the moment. http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-3-0-6-MTOM-WS-Security-Exception-td5774657.html which means it wasn't just me :)